# setup SSL connection with JSSE (Javase6) and self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, self-signed, jsse

I'm trying to build a simple client/server system wich uses SSLSocket to exchange data. (JavaSE 6)
The server must have its own certificate, clients don't need one.

I started with this
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CreateKeystore
To generate key for the server and a self signed certificate.
To sum it up:

```
    Create a new keystore and self-signed certificate with corresponding public/private keys. 
keytool -genkeypair -alias mytest -keyalg RSA -validity 7 -keystore /scratch/stores/server.jks

    Export and examine the self-signed certificate.
keytool -export -alias mytest -keystore /scratch/stores/server.jks -rfc -file server.cer

    Import the certificate into a new truststore.
keytool -import -alias mytest -file server.cer -keystore /scratch/stores/client.jks
```

Then in my server code I do

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/scratch/stores/server.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");

SSLServerSocketFactory sf = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket)sf.createServerSocket( port );

Socket s = sslServerSocket.accept();
```

I am basically missing some point because I get a "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled." when I try to run the server.

Can it be a problem with the certificate? When using -validity  in keytool the certificate gets self-signed, so it should work if I'm not wrong.

Reading the docs seems that setting the property "javax.net.ssl.keyStore" is sufficient for the SSLContext to setup correctly. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I messed up things a little, complete solution is here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1531716